# I want to fetch web output from my Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications

I have obtained the web output from my Flutter project, but it doesn't display the images retrieved from the internet. I have also used the SVG package.

```
Container(
              width: 107.w,
              height: 107.h,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.teal,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.r),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/111x111'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
```

The reason for this issue is what, and how should it be resolved?

*Web preview:*
[web preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGRlD.jpg)

*Android preview:*
[Android preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FhrE.jpg)

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to retrieve images?

Comment: Container(
              width: 107.w,
              height: 107.h,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.teal,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.r),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/111x111'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),

Answer (score 0):

Seems it works using another image.

```
Container(
      width: 107,
      height: 107,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.teal,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        image: const DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

I suppose the image you are trying to display has a transparent background, and this may result in different behavior depending on the platform.